# ASP.NET Membership users disappear

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership, membership-provider

I started creating a project using the membership classes and I keep adding a few users to test, and when I want to continue the next day, those users are GONE.

When I query the membership table I can still see the records but the Web Site Administration Tool tells me I have NO users. This has happened quiet a bit and I am worried if I should even use that for my project now.

Am I missing something?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Steve

Comment: yeah, what bryan said. without some relevant sections from config files this is about all the help you are going to get here i think.

Answer (score 2):

Poltergiests?  Do all these Users have a different ApplicationID?  Did you forget to set the applicationName property in web.config?

Generally speaking, this feature is quite mature and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. I just change ApplicationID for all Users in "aspnetdb.aspnet_Users" to my relevant ApplicationID and it works. Thanks for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default membership provider? I had the same problem, but with the MongoDB.Web provider, the problem was that when I upgraded to the new version, it expected to see a "usernameLower" field on each record, which obviously wasn't there yet.